# How to correctly use std::atomic_signal_fence()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11, atomic

cppreference.com documents this function as "fence between a thread and a signal handler executed in the same thread". But I found no example on the Internet.

I wonder whether or not the following psuedo-code correctly illustrates the function of `std::atomic_signal_fence()`:

```
int n = 0;
SignalObject s;

void thread_1()
{
    s.wait();
    std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    assert(1 == n); // never fires ???
}

void thread_2()
{
    n = 1;
    s.signal();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(thread_1);
    std::thread t2(thread_2);

    t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

Comment: I think a signal handler is a from a unix system type signal, which has special threading rules.

Comment: You should declare `n` to be `volatile`, otherwise the compiler may optimize the read away.

Comment: You don't have any signal handlers in your code, so no, the code does not demonstrate anything meaningful about `atomic_signal_fence`.

Comment: @StefanDragnev - with proper fences there's no need for `volatile`. That's what atomics and fences are all about.

Comment: @PeteBecker - without `volatile` the compiler may optimize the access to the global variable, e.g. load it only once into a register, instead of loading it every time it's mentioned. Not using `volatile` doesn't mean the compiler knows that the variable's value may change in non-obvious ways, even when using explicit fences.

Comment: @StefanDragnev - no, with a fence or any other atomic operation (with an appropriate memory access specifier) the compiler is not allowed to do that. In that context, `volatile` is redundant.

Comment: A `signal_fence` is a ["compiler" barrier](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/): it prevents compile-time reordering/combining/hoisting of memory operations, but will never emit a hardware memory barrier instructions.  Jeff Preshing's blog is excellent at explaining this stuff, definitely a must-read if you're unsure about memory-ordering stuff.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, your code does not demonstrate correct usage of `atomic_signal_fence`. As you quote cppreference.com, `atomic_signal_fence` only perform synchronization between a signal handler and other code running on the same thread. That means that it *does not* perform synchronization between two *different* threads. Your example code shows two different threads.

The C++ spec contains the following notes about this function:

> *Note:* compiler optimizations and reorderings of loads and stores are inhibited in the same way as with `atomic_thread_fence`, but the hardware fence instructions that atomic_thread_fence would have inserted are not emitted.
>
> *Note:* `atomic_signal_fence` can be used to specify the order in which actions performed by the thread become visible to the signal handler.

Here's an example of correct, if not motivating, usage:

```
static_assert(2 == ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE, "this implementation does not guarantee that std::atomic<int> is always lock free.");

std::atomic<int> a = 0;
std::atomic<int> b = 0;

extern "C" void handler(int) {
    if (1 == a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
        std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        assert(1 == b.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    }

    std::exit(0);
}

int main() {
    std::signal(SIGTERM, &handler);

    b.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    a.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

The assertion, if encountered, is guaranteed to hold true.

Comment: Are A and B necessarily atomic in your example?

Comment: @Alex They need to have atomicity. Technically, it's almost never guaranteed w/o atomic.

Answer (score 6):

In your example, you want to use `std::atomic_thread_fence` (which generates machine code to perform thread synchronization); not `std::atomic_signal_fence` (which only disables compiler memory reordering optimizations on atomic variables).
As was said by others, `std::atomic_signal_fence` is only intended for signals on the same thread as the atomic operations (I believe it would also hold true for structured/vectored exception handlers on Windows, but don't quote me on that).